# How to exit script if schema is connected to the sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, database-administration

I have this .sh script to check if the user is present if yes then it drops the user using sqlplus. but the main problem is this when the user is connected in SQL developer it does not drop the user nor stop the script what I want to do is if the user is not dropped then it should stop the script.

```
echo "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dba_users WHERE username = '$schemas';" > check_user.sql
echo "exit" >> check_user.sql

result=\$(sqlplus -S / as sysdba @check_user.sql | grep -o -E '[0-9]+')

if [[ \$result -ge 1 ]]; then
    echo "Dropping user: $schemas"
    echo "drop user $schemas cascade;" > drop_schema.sql
    echo "exit" >> drop_schema.sql
    sqlplus -S / as sysdba @drop_schema.sql
    rm drop_schema.sql
else
    echo "User $schemas do not exist."
fi

rm check_user.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a very dangerous script. "`drop user cascade`" means drop all their objects. *That will destroy data* if they have tables. I suggest you not attempt to script something this destructive. Further, if you have users connected, why would you want to drop the user? Users are dropped when they are no longer needed; apparently something still needs these.

But to answer your question: first of all, remove the `CASCADE` option. Then place the command: `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE` at the head of your script. If it attempts to drop a user that is still connected, it will throw an error and SQL*Plus will immediately exit.

If you really do want to blow away entire schemas (all their objects), then do so manually, not via scripting. If you insist on scripting it, then you will want to kill any connected sessions first:

```
BEGIN
  FOR rec_session IN (SELECT * FROM gv$session WHERE username = '$schemas')
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '''||rec_session.sid||','||rec_session.serial#||',@'||rec_session.inst_id||''''; -- if non-RAC, leave out the ,inst_id piece.
  END LOOP;
END;
```

You may also have to use `gv$access` to kill any sessions by *other* users who happen to be using the objects in the schema you want to drop. You can't drop an object that's in use, so you have to stop everybody from using it first. Another reason to not script this.

Lastly, you may consider writing the whole thing as an anonymous PL/SQL block merely initiated by shell rather than doing all your programming logic in shell. You'd have far less points of potential failure.